# Outlook Web Add-In version restrictions via manifest

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on Outlook Add-In that requires:

Blockquote

- API 1.3
- Command buttons

So I want to restrict Add-In from being showed on OWA or Desktop clients that don't support both of this.

That's what I did in the `OfficeApp` section of the manifest to restrict OWA 2013 that doesn't work with `1.3` API, that should help with Outlook Web App (Exchange 2013 On-Premise).

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <Set Name="Mailbox"/>
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

But I've got few questions regarding next steps

1. Is there a way to prevent Add-In from showing on the clients that
   don't support command buttons?  (OWA/Desktop)
2. Should I expect that Outlook 2013 Desktop (max API supported is 1.3) that worked with Exchange 2016 is the same for a user as if he used Exchange 2013? (I don't have Exchange 2013 to try myself)
3. Does `DefaultMinVersion="1.3"` guarantee that users without `December 8, 2015, update for Outlook 2013 (KB3114349)` won't see Add-In that doesn't work properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use the [Version Overrides](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/define-add-in-commands) section of the manifest, clients that support it will show these commands. In order to prevent the legacy portion of the manifest from appearing in clients that don't support it, you can use a rule that will never evaluate to true like below in your `FormSettings` section:

```
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
</Rule>
```